# How does VHDL deal with overflow?

Tags: binary, vhdl, fpga, addition

I am working on a design where I believe some overflow may be occurring that I need to deal with. In order to solve my problem I need to understand how VHDL deals with binary overflow. Some sample code is below.

```
signal temp   : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "11111111"; 
signal temp_2 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := "11111111";
signal result : std_logic_vector (8 downto 0) := "000000000";

result <= temp + temp_2 ;
```

Obviously this does not have the relevant libraries called, but it gives an idea of the code I am working with. My question is this : how does this binary addition work (temp + temp_2) i.e what would the signal `result` be after running this code? Right now, I am getting a error in the compilation because `result` is 9 bits and its expecting 8 bits. Any explanation of exactly how this binary addition works would be very helpful!

Comment: You should be using `signed` and `unsigned` rather than `std_logic_vector` for mathematical operations. Addition of two `std_logic_vector`s is not standard VHDL (there's a **non-standard** library that allows you to do so, but you shouldn't be using it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VHDL is strongly typed.  Any time you assign a signal, you need to match types and widths.

For types: You cannot assign an integer typed signal to a std_logic_vector signal, the compiler will throw an error.  You must convert the integer to std_logic_vector first.

For widths: You need to always match width assignments perfectly.  In your case, the tool is mad at you because you're assigning something that is 8 bits wide to the signal result which is 9 bits wide.

In order to accomplish what you want, you must use sign-extension.  Are you inputs signed or unsigned?  If they are unsigned, just add a '0' in the most significant bit position.  If they are signed, you must determine the sign of bit position 7, then extend that into bit position 8.

Here's how you could do in both cases:

```
temp_extended_unsigned <= '0' & temp(7 downto 0);
temp_extended_signed   <= temp(7) & temp(7 downto 0);

temp_2_extended_unsigned <= '0' & temp_2(7 downto 0);
temp_2_extended_signed   <= temp_2(7) & temp_2(7 downto 0);

result <= temp_extended_unsigned + temp_2_extended_unsigned; -- unsigned case
result <= temp_extended_signed   + temp_2_extended_signed; -- signed case
```

Note that adding 1 bit position works fine for addition, but what about multiplication?  You must consider your operation to be performed... multiplying two 8 bit wide vectors will produce a result that is 16 bits wide, so you must do sign-extension on the upper 8 bits in that example.

Comment: Also note that the resize() function from ieee.numeric_std package can correctly extend signed vectors (and also keeps the sign when shrinking them):
data_out <= resize(data_in, data_out'length);
(And there's the sign-extension function SXT() in the package std_logic_arith, but that's not a standard library and also reads a bit cryptical.)

Comment: This seemed to solve the problem at first, but now I have realized that it has introduced a two clock cycle delay in the result. Is this because of the time it takes to complete binary addition and create the new vectors? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: If you create registered logic by putting this in a clocked process, then yes it will create additional delay.  You could put this outside the process and it will create combinational logic.